# Failed to Load Module in Jboss

Tags: java, jboss, apache-axis, jboss-eap-6

I am setting up a Dynamic Web Project which has SOAP services. So I used Axis2 Runtime (Axis2-1.7.5). I am deploying this application on Jboss EAP 6.1 Server. While starting the application, I am getting the below Linkage error though axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar is already there in classpath.

```
14:43:00,203 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/MyWS]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Loading Spring root WebApplicationContext
14:43:01,169 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Failed to define class org.apache.axis2.jaxws.catalog.impl.OASISCatalogManager in Module "deployment.MyWSEAR.ear.MyWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/apache/axis2/jaxws/catalog/impl/OASISCatalogManager (Module "deployment.MyWSEAR.ear.MyWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.loadDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:700) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.getDefinition(WSDL4JWrapper.java:656) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.commonPartsURLConstructor(WSDL4JWrapper.java:224) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.util.WSDL4JWrapper.<init>(WSDL4JWrapper.java:148) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setWSDLDefinitionOnDBC(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1246) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.setupWsdlDefinition(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:1163) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:352) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.ServiceDescriptionImpl.<init>(ServiceDescriptionImpl.java:297) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:255) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescriptionFromDBCMap(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:327) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.impl.DescriptionFactoryImpl.createServiceDescription(DescriptionFactoryImpl.java:216) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.DescriptionFactory.createAxisService(DescriptionFactory.java:564) [axis2-metadata-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport.createAxisService(JAXWSDeployerSupport.java:259) [axis2-jaxws-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport.deployClasses(JAXWSDeployerSupport.java:223) [axis2-jaxws-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployerSupport.deployClasses(JAXWSDeployerSupport.java:161) [axis2-jaxws-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.deployServicesInWARClassPath(JAXWSDeployer.java:95) [axis2-jaxws-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.framework.JAXWSDeployer.init(JAXWSDeployer.java:66) [axis2-jaxws-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.initializeDeployers(DeploymentEngine.java:938) [axis2-kernel-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.setConfigContext(DeploymentEngine.java:931) [axis2-kernel-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.setConfigContext(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:355) [axis2-kernel-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:89) [axis2-kernel-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620) [axis2-transport-http-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471) [axis2-transport-http-1.7.5.jar:1.7.5]
    at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:120) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/resolver/CatalogManager
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.resolver.CatalogManager from [Module "deployment.MyWSEAR.ear.MyWS.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
    ... 49 more

14:43:01,583 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS018559: Deployed "MyWSEAR.ear" (runtime-name : "MyWSEAR.ear")
14:43:01,585 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
```

Am I making any mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class that is not found is `org.apache.xml.resolver.CatalogManager` which in the distribution from apache is in xml-resolver-1.2.jar -- make sure that is (also) available.